# What is the min x/y and max x/y coordinates of the UK using epsg 27700?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, united-kingdom

I need to get a precise point of the min/max x/y coordinates of the UK.
Anyone know if theres an official point or something close enough?

Comment: See https://epsg.io/27700

Comment: How do you define UK?

Comment: 0,0 to 700000,1300000 in epsg:27700

Comment: @TomazicM epsg.io is unreliable, see this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441046/difference-between-area-of-use-and-wgs84-bounds-on-epsg-io-which-one-is-releva