# Difference between area of use and WGS84 bounds on epsg.io - which one is relevant?

Tags: epsg, web

According to epsg.io, [EPSG:25833](https://epsg.io/25833) has "accuracy 1.0 m". I think I have to use it in the right region of the world to have this level of accuracy. The website also states:

> Area of use: Europe between 12°E and 18°E: Austria; Denmark - offshore
> and offshore; Germany - onshore and offshore; Norway including
> Svalbard - onshore and offshore.

[image]

while providing a map:

[image]

The red polygon is not showing the area described by the text.

It also says:

> WGS84 bounds:
> -16.1 32.88
> 40.18 84.73

[image]

The red polygon shows the WGS84 bounds, I think.

Is it ok to use `25833` everywhere within the red polygon (ie within "WGS84 bounds"), or should I stick to "[a]rea of use"?

Comment: I see `Europe - onshore and offshore: Albania; Andorra; Austria; Belgium; Bosnia and Herzegovina; Bulgaria; Croatia; Cyprus; Czechia; Denmark; Estonia; Faroe Islands; Finland; France; Germany; Gibraltar; Greece; Hungary; Ireland; Italy; Kosovo; Latvia; Liechtenstein; Lithuania; Luxembourg; Malta; Moldova; Monaco; Montenegro; Netherlands; North Macedonia; Norway including Svalbard and Jan Mayen; Poland; Portugal; Romania; San Marino; Serbia; Slovakia; Slovenia; Spain; Sweden; Switzerland; United Kingdom (UK) including Channel Islands and Isle of Man; Vatican City State.`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question to incorporate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the official source https://epsg.org/crs_25833/ETRS89-UTM-zone-33N.html?
There must be some problem with the data that epsg.io site uses.

[image]